# Can't get active session of an eclipselink's EntityManager with spring

Tags: spring, persistence, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, aop

I have a class that is responsible for execute stored procedure, it was working fine when I was using JTA... But cause I have some problems with redeploy, I removed JTA and I'm using local entity manager with spring:

```
 <bean id="entityManagerFactoryErp" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="erpPU"/>
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerErp" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryErp"/>
</bean>
```

Now I get a NullPointerException when I try to get active session:

```
public class ExecutadorProcedimentoArmazenado extends BaseDao implements IExecutadorProcedimentoArmazenado {

    public boolean executar(String nomeProcedimento) {
        DataReadQuery query = configurarQuery(nomeProcedimento);
        registro = executarProcedimento(query);
        int resultado = Integer.parseInt(recuperarValorDeSaida("RESULTADO"));
        mensagem = recuperarValorDeSaida("MSGERRO");
        return resultado == 0;
    }
    .
    .
    private Session configurarSessao() {
        JpaEntityManager jpaEntityManager = JpaHelper.getEntityManager(entityManager);
        return jpaEntityManager.getActiveSession();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

**ADDED**

Probably the problem is that entityManager doesn't have a transaction. I'm trying create the transaction with spring aop, it works for all other classes, but doesn't works for interface IExecutadorProcedimentoArmazenado:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryErp" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="erpPU"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerErp" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryErp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerErp"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryErp"/>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txExecutadorProcedimento" transaction-manager="transactionManagerErp">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="executar" rollback-for="Exception" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="operacoesExecutadorProcedimento" expression="execution(* com.hrgi.persistencia.IExecutadorProcedimentoArmazenado.executar(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txExecutadorProcedimento" pointcut-ref="operacoesExecutadorProcedimento"/>
</aop:config>
```

Could someone explain me why I can't get the Session for me invoke stored procedure??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spring way of doing this is to simply inject the `EntityManager` with the `@PersistenceContext` annotation and return the delegate...

```
public class ExecutadorProcedimentoArmazenado extends BaseDao implements IExecutadorProcedimentoArmazenado {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entitymanager

  private Session configurarSessao() {
    return ((JpaEntityManager) entityManager.getDelegate()).getActiveSession();
  }
```

If the active session is null, it means there **is no active session**.  I tested this and outside of a transaction, it gives an NPE.  Inside a transaction, the code above works.  Tested with Spring 3.1 / Eclipselink 2.0.

Comment: Didn't worked... java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session

Comment: I updated the cast to JPAEntityManager (I don't use eclipselink).  Since you are using spring, have you also considered using something like SimpleJdbcCall?

Comment: Your AOP configuration looks correct, however why are you still getting the EntityManager from eclipselink's JPAHelper.  I'm not sure Spring is managing the EntityManager if you get it that way.  Can you try the annotation based approach from my code sample?  I would strongly recommend using @Transactional annotations vs the AOP approach you used in your code sample.  Again, I was able to get the active session using my code sample with Transactional and PersistenceContext annotations which is the current Spring best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your container in this case is Spring and is likely returning null from entityManager.getDelegate(), resulting in an NPE on jpaEntityManager.getActiveSession().  Try starting a transaction, or getting the EntityManager from an unwrapped EclipseLink EntityManagerFactory directly instead.

Comment: Tried unwrap using entityManager.unwrap(EntityManagerImpl.class); but got:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available

Comment: Sorry, I was suggesting you get/unwrap the EntityManagerFactory and obtain an EclipseLink EntityManager from it directly rather than unwrap the EntityManager from Spring. That, or try starting a transaction in Spring and then unwrap the EntityManager.